# Input Onkeyup can be avoided by form autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, validation, onkeyup

I'm validating a field using OnKeyUp. Unfortunately it is not running when the user selects an autocomplete suggestion in his browser.

I would like to know if there is any way I can trigger my JavaScript when the user clicks in the browser input suggestions.

Comment: Best solution, keep autocomplete disabled, and use the original value from textbox...

Answer (score 2):

For IE, you can listen to `onpropertychange`. For FF/Chrome, you can listen to `oninput`. IE9 supports oninput if you are not in quirks mode, so you may need some kind of browser-sniffing or feature-detection code to prevent the event from firing twice.

[Here is a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYZWu/). You'll have to input some value and submit once for it to be in your browser's autocomplete history. Then you'll see what event it fires when you click on the autocomplete suggestion.

Another option is to disable autocomplete entirely for a given input field:

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" id="myfield" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One options you could take would be triggering events using the custom event model by YUI 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#customevent

By doing this you can explicitly *fire/trigger* the way you see fit

Comment: i don't think this addresses his question. he has no way of knowing when to explicitly fire the trigger, because nothing in JS is telling him that the user has clicked on an autocomplete suggestion.